video over 5 seconds can't be compressed
I am doing a flutter app and my user tries to add video from gallery. What is under 5 sec works , the rest over it doesn't. What I should add? I added packages like compress video , uuid anything , nothing works , dart:typed data , a lot of approaches , even to make the quality worst of the video , nothing worked
   Class VideoContent extends StatefulWidget {
  final String day;
  final bool allowEditing;
  final String programId;
  final int scheduleIndex;

  const VideoContent({
    Key? key,
    required this.day,
    required this.allowEditing,
    required this.programId,
    required this.scheduleIndex,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _VideoContentState createState() => _VideoContentState();
}

class _VideoContentState extends State<VideoContent> {
  final FirebaseFirestore _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  final FirebaseStorage _storage = FirebaseStorage.instance;
  final uuid = Uuid();
  List<dynamic> workoutVideos = [];
  bool isLoading = true;
  String errorMessage = '';

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _loadWorkoutVideos();
  }

  Future<void> _loadWorkoutVideos() async {
    try {
      print('Loading workout videos for ${widget.day} in program ${widget.programId}');
      final doc = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('programs').doc(widget.programId).get();
      
      if (!doc.exists) {
        throw Exception('Program document does not exist');
      }

      final programData = doc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
      print('Program data: $programData');

      if (!programData.containsKey('workout_schedule')) {
        throw Exception('workout_schedule field is missing in the program document');
      }

      final workoutSchedule = programData['workout_schedule'] as List<dynamic>;
      print('Workout schedule: $workoutSchedule');

      if (widget.scheduleIndex < workoutSchedule.length) {
        final daySchedule = workoutSchedule[widget.scheduleIndex];
        print('Day schedule: $daySchedule');

        // Create an empty workout_videos array if it doesn't exist
        if (!daySchedule.containsKey('workout_videos')) {
          print('Creating empty workout_videos array for this day');
          daySchedule['workout_videos'] = [];
          
          // Update Firestore with the new empty workout_videos array
          await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('programs').doc(widget.programId).update({
            'workout_schedule': workoutSchedule,
          });
        }

        setState(() {
          workoutVideos = daySchedule['workout_videos'] ?? [];
          isLoading = false;
        });
        print('Workout videos loaded: $workoutVideos');
      } else {
        throw Exception('Invalid schedule index');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error loading workout videos: $e');
      setState(() {
        isLoading = false;
        errorMessage = 'Error loading workout videos: $e';
      });
    }
  }

  Future<void> _updateWorkoutVideo(int index, Map<String, dynamic> updatedVideo) async {
    setState(() {
      workoutVideos[index] = updatedVideo;
    });
    await _updateFirestore();
  }

  Future<void> _updateFirestore() async {
    try {
      final doc = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('programs').doc(widget.programId).get();
      final programData = doc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
      final workoutSchedule = programData['workout_schedule'] as List<dynamic>;
      
      workoutSchedule[widget.scheduleIndex]['workout_videos'] = workoutVideos;

      await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('programs').doc(widget.programId).update({
        'workout_schedule': workoutSchedule,
      });

      print('Firestore updated successfully');
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error updating Firestore: $e');
      setState(() {
        errorMessage = 'Error updating workout: $e';
      });
    }
  }

  Future<void> _addWorkoutVideo() async {
    final ImagePicker _picker = ImagePicker();
    final XFile? video = await _picker.pickVideo(source: ImageSource.gallery);

    if (video != null) {
      File videoFile = File(video.path);
      String fileName = path.basename(videoFile.path);
      String videoUrl = await _uploadVideoToFirebase(videoFile, fileName);

      final newVideo = {
        'id': DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString(),
        'name': 'New Workout Video',
        'videoUrl': videoUrl,
        'repetitions': 0,
        'sets': 0,
      };

      setState(() {
        workoutVideos.add(newVideo);
      });

      await _updateFirestore();
    }
  }

  Future<String> _uploadVideoToFirebase(File videoFile, String fileName) async {
    FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.instance;
    Reference ref = storage.ref().child('workout_videos/$fileName');
    UploadTask uploadTask = ref.putFile(videoFile);
    TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot = await uploadTask;
    String downloadUrl = await taskSnapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
    return downloadUrl;
  }

  Future<void> _deleteWorkoutVideo(int index) async {
    setState(() {
      workoutVideos.removeAt(index);
    });

    await _updateFirestore();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.day),
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        foregroundColor: Colors.white,
      ),
      body: isLoading
          ? Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
          : errorMessage.isNotEmpty
              ? Center(child: Text(errorMessage, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red)))
              : workoutVideos.isEmpty
                  ? Center(
                      child: Text(
                        'No workout videos available for this day.\nTap the + button to add a video.',
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, color: Colors.grey[600]),
                      ),
                    )
                  : ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: workoutVideos.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        final video = workoutVideos[index];
                        return WorkoutVideoItem(
                          video: video,
                          onUpdate: (updatedVideo) => _updateWorkoutVideo(index, updatedVideo),
                          onDelete: () => _deleteWorkoutVideo(index),
                          allowEditing: widget.allowEditing,
                        );
                      },
                    ),
      floatingActionButton: widget.allowEditing
          ? FloatingActionButton(
              onPressed: _addWorkoutVideo,
              child: Icon(Icons.add),
              backgroundColor: Colors.orange,
            )
          : null,
    );
  }
}

class WorkoutVideoItem extends StatefulWidget {
  final Map<String, dynamic> video;
  final Function(Map<String, dynamic>) onUpdate;
  final VoidCallback onDelete;
  final bool allowEditing;

  const WorkoutVideoItem({
    Key? key,
    required this.video,
    required this.onUpdate,
    required this.onDelete,
    required this.allowEditing,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _WorkoutVideoItemState createState() => _WorkoutVideoItemState();
}

class _WorkoutVideoItemState extends State<WorkoutVideoItem> {
  late VideoPlayerController _videoPlayerController;
  ChewieController? _chewieController;
  late TextEditingController _nameController;
  late TextEditingController _repsController;
  late TextEditingController _setsController;
  bool _isVideoLoaded = false;
  bool _isVideoError = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _nameController = TextEditingController(text: widget.video['name']);
    _repsController = TextEditingController(text: widget.video['repetitions'].toString());
    _setsController = TextEditingController(text: widget.video['sets'].toString());
    _initializeVideoPlayer();
  }

  void _initializeVideoPlayer() {
    _videoPlayerController = VideoPlayerController.network(widget.video['videoUrl']);
    _videoPlayerController.initialize().then((_) {
      setState(() {
        _isVideoLoaded = true;
        _isVideoError = false;
        _chewieController = ChewieController(
          videoPlayerController: _videoPlayerController,
          aspectRatio: _videoPlayerController.value.aspectRatio,
          autoPlay: false,
          looping: false,
        );
      });
    }).catchError((error) {
      print('Error loading video: $error');
      setState(() {
        _isVideoLoaded = false;
        _isVideoError = true;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _videoPlayerController.dispose();
    _chewieController?.dispose();
    _nameController.dispose();
    _repsController.dispose();
    _setsController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  Future<void> _pickVideo() async {
    final ImagePicker _picker = ImagePicker();
    final XFile? video = await _picker.pickVideo(source: ImageSource.gallery);

    if (video != null) {
      try {
        final MediaInfo? compressedVideo = await VideoCompress.compressVideo(
          video.path,
          quality: VideoQuality.MediumQuality,
          deleteOrigin: false,
        );

        if (compressedVideo?.file == null) {
          throw Exception('Video compression failed');
        }

        String fileName = _generateShortFileName(compressedVideo!.file!.path);
        String videoUrl = await _uploadVideoToFirebase(compressedVideo.file!, fileName);

        final updatedVideo = {
          ...widget.video,
          'videoUrl': videoUrl,
        };
        widget.onUpdate(updatedVideo);
        _initializeVideoPlayer();
      } catch (e) {
        print('Error processing video: $e');
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
          SnackBar(content: Text('Failed to process video. Please try again.')),
        );
      } finally {
        await VideoCompress.deleteAllCache();
      }
    }
  }

  String _generateShortFileName(String filePath) {
    final bytes = utf8.encode(filePath);
    final hash = sha256.convert(bytes);
    return hash.toString().substring(0, 8) + '.mp4';
  }

  Future<String> _uploadVideoToFirebase(File videoFile, String fileName) async {
    try {
      FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.instance;
      Reference ref = storage.ref().child('workout_videos/$fileName');
      
      // Read file as bytes
      List<int> videoBytes = await videoFile.readAsBytes();
      
      // Upload bytes
      final metadata = SettableMetadata(contentType: 'video/mp4');
      UploadTask uploadTask = ref.putData(Uint8List.fromList(videoBytes), metadata);
      
      // Wait for the upload to complete
      await uploadTask;
      
      // Get download URL
      String downloadUrl = await ref.getDownloadURL();
      return downloadUrl;
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error uploading video: $e');
      throw e;
    }
  }

  void _updateVideo() {
    final updatedVideo = {
      ...widget.video,
      'name': _nameController.text,
      'repetitions': int.tryParse(_repsController.text) ?? 0,
      'sets': int.tryParse(_setsController.text) ?? 0,
    };
    widget.onUpdate(updatedVideo);
  }

  void _showVideoPreview(BuildContext context) {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return Dialog(
          child: Container(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.8,
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.6,
            child: _chewieController != null
                ? Chewie(
                    controller: _chewieController!,
                  )
                : Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8, vertical: 4),
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                // Video thumbnail
                GestureDetector(
                  onTap: _isVideoLoaded ? () => _showVideoPreview(context) : null,
                  child: Container(
                    width: 100,
                    height: 100,
                    child: _isVideoLoaded
                        ? AspectRatio(
                            aspectRatio: _videoPlayerController.value.aspectRatio,
                            child: VideoPlayer(_videoPlayerController),
                          )
                        : _isVideoError
                            ? Container(
                                color: Colors.grey[300],
                                child: Center(child: Icon(Icons.error, color: Colors.red)),
                              )
                            : Container(
                                color: Colors.grey[300],
                                child: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
                              ),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(width: 16),
                // Workout details
                Expanded(
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      // Workout name
                      widget.allowEditing
                          ? TextField(
                              controller: _nameController,
                              decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Workout Name'),
                            )
                          : Text(widget.video['name'], style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                      SizedBox(height: 8),
                      // Reps and Sets
                      Row(
                        children: [
                          Expanded(
                            child: widget.allowEditing
                                ? TextField(
                                    controller: _repsController,
                                    decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Reps'),
                                    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                                  )
                                : Text('Reps: ${widget.video['repetitions']}'),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(width: 16),
                          Expanded(
                            child: widget.allowEditing
                                ? TextField(
                                    controller: _setsController,
                                    decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Sets'),
                                    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                                  )
                                : Text('Sets: ${widget.video['sets']}'),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                // Delete button
                if (widget.allowEditing)
                  IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.delete, color: Colors.red),
                    onPressed: widget.onDelete,
                  ),
              ],
            ),
            if (widget.allowEditing)
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: [
                  ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: _updateVideo,
                    child: Text('Save Changes'),
                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                      backgroundColor: Colors.orange,
                    ),
                  ),
                  ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: _pickVideo,
                    child: Text('Change Video'),
                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                      backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

